# Tortoisegit can't compare file to repo

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I checked out a repo with Tortoisegit.

I modified a file.

I committed it to the master branch.

All this happens just fine.

HOWEVER when I try to display a log for that file, nothing shows.

When I try to diff it with previous (from the context menu), Git says it doesn't exist in the given tree.

When I look in the repo browser, the file is not there in the tree.

So something is not consistent.  If the file isn't there, how was I able to check it out?  And how did I check it in?  I haven't switched branch.  How can I troubleshoot this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I checked it in"?

Comment: Did you change the branch? What shows the log dialog for the whole project?

Comment: @MrTux corrected above - I committed the file to master branch.  Log dialog for whole project shows the file wasn't present in the last commit (other files which I committed were) even though the commit dialog did show the file modified/selected for commit at the time.

Comment: This turned out to be a git issue not tortoisegit, solution here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33870015/git-committed-file-but-its-not-in-the-repo/33897248#33897248