# Git committed file but it's not in the repo

Tags: git

I staged and committed a file to a local git repository and this appeared to work correctly.

However on examining the repository it doesn't appear to be present.  Excerpt from my command session:

```
D:\myproject>git log -1 --stat
...
 myfile.h        |    27 +-
...
30 files changed, 18501 insertions(+), 15303 deletions(-)

D:\myproject>git ls-files myfile.h

D:\myproject>
```

This file should have been present in the repository for a long time, over multiple commits.
Obviously I am worried that commit may also have silently failed for other files.

How can I ensure my changes are all committed correctly?

Comment: git ls-files shows "information about files in the index and the working tree". What if your file was committed, but it's not present in the index or the working tree?

Comment: It is present in the working tree

Comment: what happen if you git ls-files on any of the other 37 files in that last commit ?

Comment: Tried a bunch of them, most are visible in ls-files, one is oddly visible three times.  Presumably this technique could be used to pick up obvious problems with previous commits, though it wouldn't guarantee that the correct changes were committed?  Is there an easy way to automate it, e.g. get git to output changed files on commits in a format that can be piped into ls-files?

Comment: My bet is: you're probably in an unmerged state (which would explain why you see some files 3 times). Run a git status to have an idea of what's going on and what you need to fix ;)

Comment: Ok yes the triple listed file is a conflict.  I tried to merge changes from repo into working directory to fix this problem already.  The problematic `myfile.h` is not one of the conflicts though.  Oddly it doesn't appear in the list of untracked files returned by `git status` even though it isn't visible in `ls-files`.  What could be going on there?

Comment: Maybe one of those: `git ls-files --ignored --exclude-standard --debug` and `git ls-files --killed --debug` could yield interesting results ?

Comment: Ok, I got it - it's a case issue.  One of the parent directories exists as two separate entries in the repo, `Folder` and `folder` and being on Windows these are the same thing on the working tree.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33873620/git-config-core-ignorecase-doesnt-ignore-case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file turned out to be present in the repository but the path had different case.  e.g.,

Repository: `ParentFolder/myfile.h`

Working directory: `parentfolder/myfile.h`

While Windows sees these as the same path, git doesn't, even with the `ignoreCase` option set to true (`ignoreCase` apparently only affects the staging area not `git ls-files`, `git diff` etc).

The fix was to write a script comparing the output of `find` (gnu/msys find not Windows find!) to `git ls-files` to find all files affected in this way.  The affected files are those present in the repo which have a case insensitive, but not case sensitive match in the working tree.  Then for each one, delete and re-add in Git, being careful not to delete the local copy:

```
git rm --cached ParentFolder/myfile.h
git add parentfolder/myfile.h
```

And commit.